# Sending image to Bot not working with Windows 10 Skype

Tags: botframework

I am trying to send an image to my Bot.  This works in most versions of Skype, but for some reason it fails in the Windows 10 version of the Skype app.

The Bot is implemented and has been working for a while.  It can be found by going to https://www.chtter.net and adding the Skype Bot.

When an image is sent to the Bot, the image is then downloaded to AWS S3, and then forwarded to the intended recipient of the image.

The problem is that when this is done using the "Classic" desktop version of Skype it works fine.  If you send the image using the Android version of Skype, it works fine.  But using the Windows 10 app, the Bot seems to throw an "Internal Server Error", and the file that is uploaded to S3 is not viewable.  This doesn't seem to be an issue with the Bot code, since it works in many cases.  It seems to be a difference between the Windows 10 app (or how it handles the Bot interface, or something) and other versions of Skype.

Has anyone else seen this, and is there some solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are some known issues with the Skype Image Service right now (2017-12). Also, Skype does not maintain feature parity across their client app portfolio & unfortunately the Skype client differences can't be addressed from the bot-code side of things.